Error: Element type is invalid when extending DecoratorNode in Lexical
I'm trying to create a custom image plugin using Lexical's Rich Text editor. All my lexical packages are version 0.17.1.
Here's my code:
// ImageNode.jsx
import { DecoratorNode } from 'lexical';

export class ImageNode extends DecoratorNode {
  __src;

  static getType() {
    return 'image';
  }

  static clone(node) {
    return new ImageNode(node.__src, node.__key);
  }

  constructor(src, key) {
    super(key);
    this.__src = src;
  }

  createDOM() {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', this.getLatest().__src);

    const element = document.createElement('div');
    element.appendChild(img);

    return element;
  }

  exportDOM() {
    const element = document.createElement('img');
    element.setAttribute('src', this.__src);

    return { element };
  }

  static importDOM() {
    return {
      img: (node) => {
        return {
          conversion: convertImageElement,
          priority: 0,
        };
      },
    };
  }

  updateDOM() {
    return false;
  }

  static importJSON(serializedNode) {
    const { src } = serializedNode;
    const node = $createImageNode({ src });
    return node;
  }

  exportJSON() {
    return {
      src: this.__src,
      type: 'image',
      version: 1,
    };
  }

  decorate() {
    return (
      <img
        nodeKey={this.getKey()}
        src={this.__src}
      />
    );
  }
}

export function $createImageNode({ src }) {
  return new ImageNode(src);
}

export function $isImageNode(node) {
  return node instanceof ImageNode;
}

const convertImageElement = (domNode) => {
  if (domNode instanceof HTMLImageElement) {
    const { src } = domNode;
    const node = $createImageNode(src);
    return { node };
  }

  return null;
};

Whenever I try to insert a new ImageNode, this error pops up:
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `RichTextPlugin`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:20442:23)
    at createFiberFromElement (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:20463:23)
    at reconcileSingleElement (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:10513:31)
    at reconcileChildFibers2 (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:10550:43)
    at updatePortalComponent (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:15626:37)
    at beginWork (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:15941:22)
    at beginWork$1 (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:19753:22)
    at performUnitOfWork (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:19198:20)
    at workLoopSync (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:19137:13)
    at renderRootSync (chunk-3IHV7RO6.js?v=c6a6fdf4:19116:15)

I've tried ditching DecoratorNode and extend LineBreakNode or ElementNode (and adding children); they work but the behaviors of these two nodes are different from what I'm looking for. Is there a way to fix this and still use DecoratorNode?
For reference, I'm using React + JavaScript, and not React + TypeScript.
